# How should I pass the ID into collection routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am new in ruby on rails.. When the user click the buy button to the specific product, it will get the id of the product then it will redirect to another page where it will display all the details of the product(name,description,price,image etc)..

I created a custom routes which is this one below:

**Routes**

```
resources :products do // products is my name of the controller
    collection do
        get :details
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart',details_products_path, class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :get %>
```

**Controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all()
  end
  def details
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

NOTE: I also check my rake routes, the path it shows

```
details_products_path   GET /products/details(.:format) products#details
```

I notice that there's no id(like this /products/details/:id)

I also tried this one

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart',details_products_path(@products), class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :get %>
```

but im getting error

> "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#details" Couldn't find Product with 'id'= in

```
def details
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Question: How do I pass the ID into my details method that is located at my products controller

Comment: As JP mentions below, use :show, instead of details. And, link_to will work instead of button_to - `link_to "Add to Cart", @product, :class => '...'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need `product_id` in the url, you need to define it as a member route not collection

```
resources :products do
  member do
    get :details
  end
end
```

Now you will get

```
 GET /products/:id/details(.:format) products#details
```

Refer this for more details [adding-more-restful-actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: May I know what is the difference of the two? member and collection? and what is the proper way to declare a custom routes?

Comment: Member route is where you need to do some action on object like `edit`, `update`, `delete`

Comment: Collection route are routes where you do some action on class like `index`

Comment: Ooohh last more question sir, is this natural or not? When I clicked the add to cart it will become like this http://localhost:3000/products/1/details?.. but it getting all the details of that product

Comment: sorry didn't get your question. refer this link for more details http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using :show for something else, that would be the normal place for such a page.  ;)